# Textarea remaining characters not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have a textarea with pre-filled value in it. Now, I have also installed a "character remaining" line underneath the text area.

I'm not been able to achieve the default count value, if you notice on load the word count stays at "250 characters remaining", also note that the value is pre-filled with some text already so the function should count the pre-filled text by default.

The text color changes to yellow once "100 characters are remaining" and to red once "0 characters are remaining". It seems like the color doesn't change back to default when I reach the yellow color and starts removing the text to more than 100 characters.

Can someone help?

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('textarea.minchar')) {
    let element = event.target;
    let value = element.value;
    let maxLength = element.maxLength;
    let rechar = element.nextElementSibling;

    rechar.innerText = `${maxLength - Number(value.length)} characters remaining`;

    if (maxLength - Number(value.length) == 0) {
      rechar.style.color = "#E01424";
    } else if (maxLength - Number(value.length) <= 100) {
      rechar.style.color = "#CF7721";
    }
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 pl-0">
  <textarea cols="15" rows="4" placeholder="Describe this Extra in brief for your guest" class="minchar" maxlength="250">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price includes up to a full tank of petrol/diesel/charge.</textarea>
  <p class="rechar" id="test">250 characters remaining</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need another `else` block to set the `rechar.style.color` to black (`#000`) since you need to listen for a character delete event

Comment: 1. because you listen to keyup 2.you didn't change color back.

Comment: @Cyval a preview is a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to do it using jQuery, below should do the same.

**HTML Snippet:**

```
    <label class="col-md-12 pl-0">Description</label>
<div class="col-md-10 pl-0">
  <textarea cols="75" rows="5" class="minchar" maxlength="250" placeholder="Describe this Extra in brief for your guest">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price includes up to a full tank of petrol/diesel/charge.</textarea>
  <p class="rechar"></p>
  </div>
```

**jQuery Snippet:**

```
$('.minchar').on('input', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  // Get Length
  var txtLength = $(e.currentTarget).val().length;
  // Get Remaining Length
  var txtLengthRemaining = 250 - txtLength;
  // Create HTML String
  var strHtml = txtLengthRemaining+" characters remaining";
  // Fill the String & Color based on below conditions
  if(txtLengthRemaining <= 0) {
    $('.rechar').css('color', '#E01424').html(strHtml);
  } else if(txtLengthRemaining <= 100) {
    $('.rechar').css('color', '#CF7721').html(strHtml);
  } else {
    $('.rechar').css('color', '#737373').html(strHtml);
  }
});  
// Trigger event on page load by default.
$('.minchar').trigger('input');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nh147uaf/2/

Answer (score 2):

I analyzed your question content and found more than one issue there, solving them will give you an open perspective of what is happening. Let me explain.

## Define first what you will use in your code.

This will help you to understand your code better, defining useful variables first. So you don't have to call them over and over again. So, I'd suggest you to define your DOM elements references at the very beginning like this:

```
var textarea = document.querySelector(".minchar"),
    output = document.querySelector(".rechar");
var maxLength = +textarea.getAttribute("maxlength");
```

Now we have the textarea in a variable, the output div in another and the max length we shoud use.

## Handle your remaining characters in a function.

Why is this you may ask? Well, see for yourself how cleaner, readable and simpler does the code change. So, having a simple function that its only job is to update the `remaining characters output`, will let you run the function whenever you want to update it. It could be when a key is pressed, when the textarea changes, or even ***when the website is loaded***:

**The function:**

```
function outputRemainingCharacters(){
    let used = textarea.value.length;
    output.innerText = `${maxLength - +used} characters remaining`;
}
```

Adding the function to the event listener just when the website is done loading:

```
window.onload = outputRemainingCharacters;
```

As easy as that, it will then update your value from the very beginning.

## Add a default condition to your if statement.

This is due to, if you don't add a default value, you will never be able to return to the *default value* as you mention:

```
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

    outputRemainingCharacters();
    let used = textarea.value.length;
    if (maxLength - used == 0) {
        output.style.color = "#E01424";
    } else if (maxLength - used <= 100) {
        output.style.color = "#CF7721";
    } else {
        output.style.color = "#000"; //Default color
    }

});
```

As you can see, the event listener is now a lot cleaner. I also would recommend:

> Use event listeners for the specific event on the specific element you need.

This will help you not adding extra if statements to match if the event triggered on the element you want. Since we defined the text area at the very beginning, we can now just assign the event listener directly to it.

***Note:*** You should use the event listener `keydown` instead of `keyup`. This due to the fact that holding down a key will not trigger the event until the key is up. `keydown` will be more accurate here. Try holding the space key down while writing to the textbox in the following snippet and see what happens.

#### Check this example:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector(".minchar"),
    output = document.querySelector(".rechar");
var maxLength = +textarea.getAttribute("maxlength");

function outputRemainingCharacters(){
    let used = textarea.value.length;
    output.innerText = `${maxLength - +used} characters remaining`;
}

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

    outputRemainingCharacters();
    let used = textarea.value.length;
    if (maxLength - used == 0) {
        output.style.color = "#E01424";
    } else if (maxLength - used <= 100) {
        output.style.color = "#CF7721";
    } else {
        output.style.color = "#000"; //Default color
    }

});

window.onload = outputRemainingCharacters;
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 pl-0">
  <textarea cols="15" rows="4" placeholder="Describe this Extra in brief for your guest" class="minchar" maxlength="250">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price includes up to a full tank of petrol/diesel/charge.</textarea>
  <p class="rechar" id="test">250 characters remaining</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's lovely! And what if I also want to choose blue as default color instead of black?

Comment: @BillNathan Always glad to help. For that specific question, just use the respective [hexadecimal value](https://hackernoon.com/hex-colors-how-do-they-work-d8cb935ac0f), [rgb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/RGB) or [color value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) value of your desire. [This tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Color_picker_tool) might be useful. I.E, for the brightest blue `#00F` is the value.

Answer (score 1):

Add an else statement to the bottom and set color back to black like so:

```
if (maxLength - Number(value.length) <= 0) {
  rechar.style.color = "#E01424";
} else if (maxLength - Number(value.length) <= 100) {
  rechar.style.color = "#CF7721";
} else { // You can add an if statement here to check if the color is #000 yet to prevent re-renders
  rechar.style.color = "#000";
}
```

Manually triggering event the first time:

```
var evnt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evnt.initEvent('keyup', true, true); // Deprecated but still works
$('textarea.minchar').dispatchEvent(evnt);
```

Comment: @BillNathan Edited with answer you'll want to run this on load, this assumes JQuery https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent

Comment: Why would you think that a deprecated solution would be the best?

Comment: I don't, that's why I linked to the documents